# icon overlapping on my desktop (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop

My icons suddenly overlapped on my desktop. Cannot find a way to fix it. I tried to right-click and go for the options there (align etc...) but nothing. How can I fix this

[image]

Comment: Are you saying there is *no* context menu on right-clicking the Desktop? Or ist the *View* menu item missing? More info is needed.

Comment: Ctrl + Mouse Wheel.

Comment: Ctrl + Mouse Wheel just make them bigger or smaller, but still overlapping

Comment: Everything is there when right clicking, but nothing fixes it. I might have miss some option but I doubt. What were you suggesting?